# CEO from the company vs. CEO of the company

Tags: meaning

I don't understand how the following two sentences differ from each other.

1. Jeff Bezos made a bombshell announcement that he would step down as CEO **from** the company he founded.
2. Jeff Bezos made a bombshell announcement that he would step down as CEO **of** the company he founded.

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+CEO+*+Unilever&year_start=1990&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) using a "wild-card" asterisk to see which words most commonly occur between ***the CEO*** and ***Unilever***. To a first approximation, only one word ever occurs in that position.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, definitely use "of". He is CEO *of* the company.

However, there may be times when 'from' could be more appropriate, such as contexts when referring to somebody outside of that capacity. For example, you might say "Mr Jones is the head *of* my school", but if you saw him in the supermarket you might say "that's Mr Jones, he's the head *from* my school", because he is neither in the school nor currently acting in that capacity at that moment.

Comment: "from" is still acceptable in this sentence, as he is leaving the company.  He's no longer CEO, as he's stepping down **from** the position, and the company.  I'd say both sentences are fine.